# Get conversation ID in directline bot framework inline

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I am using [directline](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline) for webchat.

I want to include a refresh button on top of the chat and for that I need the conversation ID. How can I get the ID? Is it possible by using inline webchat ?
[This the refresh button that I am trying to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNnvO.png)

Comment: Where do you need the conversation ID? On your client side (js code on your page hosting the webchat)?

Comment: I want to call the [reconnect to conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-reconnect-to-conversation) when the user clicks the refresh button. For that I need the conversation ID. I need the conversation ID in js code on the hosted page of the webchat.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem, as I wanted to pass the conversation ID to my custom controller for initial authentication and correspondingly, push a custom auth data to the conversation stack of the bot framework relating to that specific conversation ID.

My hunting got me to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/357) issue post on Github:

In the 3rd post by *inmarktech* he mentions the below code:

```
var params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);
var my_token = params['my_token'];

var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
    secret: 'DIRECTLINE_SECRET'
});

BotChat.App({
    botConnection: botConnection
    ,user: { id: 'USER_ID', name: 'User' }  // user.id auto updates after first user message
}, document.getElementById("bot"));

botConnection.connectionStatus$.subscribe(function (status) {
    if (status == 2) {  // wait for connection is 'OnLine' to send data to bot
        var convID = botConnection.conversationId;
        botConnection.postActivity({
            from: { id: convID }  // because first time user ID == conversation ID
            ,type: 'event'
            ,name: 'registerUserData'    // event name as we need
            ,value: my_token   // data attached to event
        }).subscribe(function (activityId) {
            // This subscription is a MUST
            // If I remove this handler the postActivity not reaches the bot
        });
    }
});
```

as you can see he is subscribing to **botConnection.connectionStatus$** and as and when the **status** property is equal to 2(Online) you can then fetch the Conversation ID from the botConnection object.

Hope that helps :)